# Chrome Extension (content script) + React: getting React component from DOM?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I understand, there is a chrome extension 'React Dev Tools' which enables to inspect the React app. Wondering, if it's possible to read props corresponding to React component from Chrome extension content script injected on the web page.

e.g. $('.todo-list').react.props ??

Comment: ^ question is mainly about getting reference to React Node, so can access the props

Comment: Spoof React.render and assign the property: [React - getting a component from a DOM element for debugging](//stackoverflow.com/a/37230133)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't spoof React internals or expose them, another way to access the React node is like this:

```
const root = document.querySelector('[data-reactroot]');
const instance = root[Object.keys(root)[0]];
```

That will give you an object that has the root React element in the _currentElement key.